# I can't figure out why this code works fine

Tags: c, while-loop, char

C newbie here. Was wondering why doesn't this code throw and error. It has missing parentheses and comparison between characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

while ('a'<'b')

    printf("-");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Where are the missing parentheses?

Comment: `char` is an integral type so they are treated just like any other integer number type. Your comparison is comparing the char codes, which are numbers.

Comment: `char` is an integer type; comparison is allowed. No parens are missing.

Comment: The only error I see is the infinite loop.

Comment: Are asking about no curly braces `{ }` (aka brackets) in the `while` loop?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes

Comment: @Johnny Mopp  No `char` in `'a'<'b'`, just 2 `int` constants.

Answer (score 3):

'a' and 'b' are character integer constants (6.4.4.4) and comparable like any other pair of integers.  That comparison is probably evaluated at compile-time leaving you with an infinite loop:

`while(1) print("-");`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, if you are not using the curly brackets to create a block of code you if's while's etc... will execute the first line of code after the condition\loop etc...

```
while( condition )
    func1();
```

But this is bad practice, you can fool yourself thinking that the example below  will execute in a loop the 3 lines of code, in reality it will execute inside the while just the first one:

```
while( condition )
    func1(); //<- just this line will be executed inside the while loop.
    func2();
    func3();
```

Correct way:

```
while( condition )
{
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
}
```

Comment: I think you mean “statement” and not “line of code”